# NUXT with morris.js - error: 'define not defined'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Finally I got morris.js (https://github.com/bbonnin/vue-morris, external plugin) working with NUXT but theres a problem if I reload the page OR I access the subpage with the chart directly. Then the whole application crashes and I get an error 'define is not defined'.
I run nuxt in universal mode:

I already found these links, but could not get it work:

[Plugins only for browsers](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#only-for-browsers)

[Nuxt-FAQ: window not defined](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/window-document-undefined/)

[Where do I put client side scripts only](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/30)

**plugins/vue-morris.js**

```
import Raphael from 'raphael/raphael'
import jQuery from 'jquery'

// This is needed by Morris
global.Raphael = Raphael
global.jQuery = jQuery
```

**nuxt-config.js**

```
..
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-morris', mode: 'client'}
  ],
..
```

**chartSection.vue**

```
<template>
<line-chart>....</line-chart>
</template>

<script>
import { LineChart } from 'vue-morris'
import axios from "axios"

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      .... 
    };
  },
  components: {
    LineChart
  }
..
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: having the same issue, did you manage to resolve this?